# Выровнять текст внутри TextSwitcher в Android

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

Всем доброго времени суток! Прошу помощи с казалось бы элементарной задачей.

Имеется активити с такой xml разметкой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/score_textwiew"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"
        android:gravity="top|center"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#FFF" />

    <TextSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/question_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#FFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/true_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/true_button_style"
            android:text="@string/true_button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/false_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/false_button_style"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:text="@string/false_button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="24dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

На экране выглядит это приблизительно так: [image: Снимок экрана]

**Вопрос первый**: как выровнять текст внутри второго `TextSwitcher (android:id="@+id/question_text_view")`? Так, чтобы выводимый текст был всегда по самому центру этого элемента. `android:gravity="center_vertical"` не помогает.

**Вопрос второй**: как сделать так, чтобы этот самый `TextSwitcher (android:id="@+id/question_text_view")` был всегда фиксированного размера и в самом центре экрана? Дело в том, что в зависимости от длинны выводимого текста остальные элементы начинают "прыгать" то выше, то ниже. При том, что выводимый текст не больше чем сам элемент, и текст мог бы спокойно в нём разместится.